# .gitlab-ci.yml Gitlab Deploy SFTP Not Working

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, lftp

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    #- lftp -u $DEPLOY_USER,$SFTP_PASSWORD $DEPLOY_HOST -e "mirror -e -R -p ./dist/ new/ ; quit"
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; debug; open -u root,$DEPLOY_PASSWORD -p 22 $DEPLOY_HOST; mirror -Rev ./ gitlab --verbose --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
    - echo "deployment complete"
  # specify environment this job is using
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://xxxxxxxx.de/
  # needs artifacts from previous build
```

Why does the preceding `.gitlab-ci.yml` create the following error?

new Fail ->

```
--verbose --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l root xx.xx.xxx.xx sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xxx.xx (xx.xx.xxx.xx)' can't be established.
<--- ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
<--- Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
<--- 
<--- Host key verification failed.
---- Disconnecting
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l root xx.xx.xxx.xx sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xxx.xx (xx.xx.xxx.xx)' can't be established.
<--- ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxx.
<--- Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
<--- 
<--- Host key verification failed.
mirror: Fatal error: Host key verification failed.
---- Disconnecting
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Please don't add stuff like repeated `a`'s over and over to bypass SE quality measures

Answer (score 2):

You have set `ftp:ssl-allow no`, but you are connecting to port 22 which is most likely an SSL service.

Assuming you intend to use SSL for the connection.
Try:`set ftp:ssl-allow true;` as part of the lftp command.

The [lftp man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) states:

> ftp:ssl-allow (boolean)
>                 if true, try to negotiate SSL connection with FTP  server  for  non-anonymous  access.
>                 Default  is  true. This and other SSL settings are only available if lftp was compiled
>                 with an ssl/tls library.

Comment: Port 22 is unlikely to be SSL or any FTP variant, it's most likely SFTP or SSH.

Answer (score 2):

> lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; debug; open -u root,$DEPLOY_PASSWORD -p 22 $DEPLOY_HOST…"

1st, remove `set ftp:ssl-allow no;` or set it to `yes`.

2nd, you said "SFTP" in the title and use port 22; protocol SFTP **is not** FTP, it's a completely different protocol; to use it you've to make `lftp` to use the protocol by using URL with `sftp://` protocol:

```
lftp -c "debug; open -u root,$DEPLOY_PASSWORD sftp://$DEPLOY_HOST…"
```

Comment: Thanks, can u maybe help me by next Problem with verification ?

Host key verification failed.

Comment: SFTP works on top of SSH, so you have to start with `ssh -vvv $DEPLOY_HOST`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed